# Dynamic frequency scaling

Tags: windows, winapi

I would like to adjust the CPU frequency , in other word, looking for an API or c++ code for frequency scaling in windows ?

Comment: Before you ask for it, you should consider the semantics of such an API on a multiprocessing operating system where, presumably, the code you're after is running in the userspace.

Comment: that's not really something you can do in user mode... usually that's achieved with a kernel mode driver. There are things you can do to reduce the likelyhood of the CPU scaling up but beyond that you're out of luck

Comment: You should also consider the fact that in spite of your best intentions, reducing the CPU frequency might in fact *increase* power consumption. The best performance is obtained when the CPU frequency is maximized when there is code to run, and then minimized when there's no code to run. In other words: running code is usually most efficient at full speed. So, pretty much only the scheduler and the power/thermal management layer have the knowledge necessary to switch CPU frequency *efficiently*. You, in the userland, don't and won't.

Comment: I'm planning to build a program measure the CPU utilization and based on it I might reduce the CPU frequency to reduce the power consumption..

Comment: As I've said before: reducing the CPU frequency will keep the CPU running in an active state for *longer* than if it was in an inactive state, and on many CPUs it will *increase* the power consumption. Your "program" would need to be a kernel driver anyway, since the only truly realtime CPU utilization information is available in the kernel, at least on Windows, Linux and OS X.

Comment: In other words: You might be following in the path of Don Quixote, fighting windmills. Do you have any *measurements* that *show* that the power consumption on a particular CPU, under particular load conditions, is *lower* when the CPU frequency is lower? Only when you have the ability to produce such measurements can you really attempt to tweak things.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can call [SetPriorityClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set the priority of the process

You can also set the priority of a thread by calling [SetThreadPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I think the author means overclocking his PC CPU, not increasing the time his app gets on the CPU.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @KubaOber Sorry, do you see a question hidden in the text above?

Comment: Thank you all, to understand me  
I'm planning to build a program measure the CPU utilization and based on it I might reduce the CPU frequency to reduce the power consumption..

Comment: I already found an API structure for battery status and CPU utilization, but for CPU freq. adjustment Im still struggle

Answer (score 0):

The CPU clock speed is not something for which there are just some simple instructions to execute. The clock speed is controlled by the motherboard chipset, and that in turn is controlled by a motherboard-specific device driver.

You can get some control over the clock speed by using the Windows settings for power management. The usual way to slow things down and save energy is to choose a setting on this basis. Modern laptop, tablet and phone computers have extremely sophisticated algorithms but you can hint them in the direction of less power.

You may be able to automate the operation of these Windows programs, if that's all you need.

Many motherboards come with the ability to overclock, and a utility to control it. If you have such a motherboard you may be able to find a way to automate its control program, or it may provide an API. It will not be a generic solution, but one highly specific to the motherboard. Check with your motherboard supplier.

Is there a general Windows capability to do this? Not so far as I know, but there could be something hiding in there somewhere. It will be privileged call to a device driver requiring admin rights, if it exists. My be is that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: PowerWriteDCValueIndex(); / PowerWriteACValueIndex(); with  PowerSetActiveScheme(NULL, pwrGUID);